# More emoji system wide (especially on empathy)

Tags: gnome, fonts, empathy

I wanted a familiar set of emoji for the Empathy interface (I currently only use empathy for hangouts). The solution so far has been:

- Ancient and Noto fonts : I can't be sure how well Noto works, but I am sure that ancient font allows most of the AOSP Keyboard emoji to interface to the messenger.
- I installed a few bitmaps to: `/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/`

How can I get the images from [Emojipedia: Google emoji](http://emojipedia.org/google-emoji-list/) set up so that I  see those images in Empathy? Also would the main repos care about a package that does this?

EDIT:

Another link since emoji are understood by so few: [Emoji Family](http://emoji.codes/family)

Comment: Emoji aren't standardized across platforms, so until they are I doubt the main repositories care for a package as such...

Comment: Thanks for the help there, maybe if we came up with an Ubuntu set of emoji (this would also increase the curb appeal of ubuntu touch).

Comment: You still have the cross platform hell that Emoji can introduce.  Consider the number of people using emoji on iPhones, Android,  and others.  The emoji charsets don't match up on each, making the emoji relatively OS specific.  While emoji are nice to have, just adding it for Ubuntu will work for Ubuntu items but without a **globally cross platform standardized charset** you may still run into the problem of mismatches or no charsets to match a given emoji.

Comment: Emoji use the ancient font, the only cross platform silliness is in the rendering. 90% of the emoji that i've seen from the android platform render in Empathy with the ancient font, the only thing we need is to add some color images to use instead of the character itself.

Comment: You could download the Android Emoji font used on some pages [from here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+archive/jb-release/data/fonts.tar.gz) - you may already have it installed anyway.

Comment: That is a font, not a set of images, the difference is that the fonts are scalar and monochrome

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you could add new set instead you can have a workaround.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/gnome/16x16/emotes/
```

Now download the set of emoctions to this directory, so you can can override empathy icon theme on a per user basis by installing the similarly named .png icon.

Now you have to rename those icons to the same name of the default which is founded in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/emotes`.

Then all you have is to close then start again empathy and you could use the new set instead of the default one

Comment: This however does not fix the fact that there may be missing emoji charsets on the other side, which is why I condemn the endeavor for now... (given the phones recommendation in comments above)

Comment: True, it will not, I didn't read that comment before answering..

Comment: Not saying that it detracts your answer, only that it needed mentioning :)

Comment: This answer was already followed, as per my second bullet point

Comment: I think this is the only solution for now,